# Beginner's question Pandoc, LaTeX and CSL

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc

I recently discovered pandoc and I am trying to get it to process my \cite commands in a .tex file using my CSL file, outputting a formatted PDF. As far as I understand this is something that pandoc can do?

I'm trying to come up with a MWE but no luck so far. This is what I have.
I have a folder with the following .tex file

```
\title{This is the Title}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Here is some text with a reference to a bibliography citation.\cite{DeLucia:2012tt]
\section{References}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I have this references.bib file with just a single BibTex entry.

```
@article{DeLucia:2012tt,
Author = {De Lucia, Luca},
Journal = {Review of European Administrative Law},
Number = {2},
Pages = {17--45},
Title = {{Administrative Pluralism, Horizontal Cooperation and Transnational Administrative Acts}},
Volume = {5},
Year = {2012}}
```

And I'm using this shell script in OSX Terminal, where I get the following error with regard to my .bib and .csl file: "command not found". Same when I input the full path to these files, i.e. /Users/MyName/Desktop/Folder/name.bib

```
 pandoc \
-M author="Timothy Roes" \
-M date="June 2, 2016" \
-f latex \
--smart \
--bibliography=references.bib
--csl=citationstyle.csl
-o output.pdf input.tex
```

And then I have a .CSL file that I used before with Papers.app where it worked splendidly.

Comment: If you want to use CSL files you can't use `biblatex` or BibTeX (or other LaTeX bibliography packages), Pandoc will create the bibliography for you. I have therefore removed the `biblatex` and BibTeX tags. The document you show looks very TeX-y already, normally Pandoc documents look a bit different.

Comment: You need a `\documentclass` statement in your MWE, for instance `\documentclass{article}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like some typos and syntax errors were responsible for the issues.

In the tex file:

- missing `\documentclass`
- missing `biblatex` setup
- `\cite` closed with `]` instead of `}`

after fixing that the MWE compiled fine

In the script:

- syntax for metadata is `-M KEY:VALUE` not `-M KEY=VALUE`
- all line breaks have to be escaped with a `\`

So, here are the files

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\title{This is the Title}
\author{John Doe}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Here is some text with a reference to a bibliography citation.\cite{DeLucia:2012tt}
\section{References}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the script

```
pandoc input.tex -s -S\
    -M author:"Timothy Roes" \
    -M date:"June 2, 2016" \
    --bibliography=references.bib --csl=citationstyle.csl \
    -o output.pdf
```

putting it together (using [chicago-note-bibliography.csl](https://www.zotero.org/styles/chicago-note-bibliography)) results in the following

[image]